# Calculated row: How to calculate cell value of the particular column based on the values from other rows in the same column using AG Grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I want to implement a custom calculation for the specific row using the values from other rows in the same column. I found that AG Grid provides the ability to define [Column Definition Expressions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-expressions/) and [aggFunc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/aggregation/), but they don't solve what I want:

1. `Column Definition Expressions` (let's call it CDE) allow users to reference other columns of the same row
2. `aggFunc` is helpful in the case of grouping where users can use built-in functions or define custom aggregation function, which can use cell values of the same column only inside the particular group.

***I need to solve the following:***

```
Category groups         | Jan                        | Feb | Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Income                  | {it is place for aggFunc}  |     | {it is place for CDE}
    In 1                |                            |     |
    In 2                |                            |     |
    Ignored In in Net   |                            |     |
Liabilities             |                            |     |
Net Income       ???    | In 1 + In 2 - Liabilities  |     |
Net Income Total ???    | Income - Liabilities       |     |
```

In the result, it should be like this:

```
Category groups         | Jan   | Feb | Total
----------------------------------------------
Income                  | 62    |  17 |  79
    In 1                | 12    |  10 |  22
    In 2                | 20    |  5  |  25
    Ignored In in Net   | 30    |  2  |  32
Liabilities             | 15    |  10 |  25
Net Income       ???    | 17    |  5  |  22
Net Income Total ???    | 47    |  7  |  54
```

So, ***how I can define the formula (expression/aggregation function) for `Net Income` row and `Net Income Total` row by AG Grid (react)***, ***where I can refer to any needed rows within the same column*** (in the case above `Net Income = In 1 + In 2 - Liabilities` and `Net Income Total = Income - Liabilities` for Jan, Feb, etc.)? Which API can be used?

*For now, I implemented this [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/plunk/KQdZDjHKI0tUvT62) and I didn't find any clues in the official AG Grid documentation on how to implement the needed case and is it possible with this library at all...*

**UPD**. I tried to implement it by:

1. Override `getRowNodeId()` callback to have predictable rowNodeId;
2. Get rowNode by `api.getRowNode(rowId)`;
3. use [getValue()](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-miscellaneous) function which has 2 parameters `(colKey, rowNode)` and in theory it should return the value of the target column of the specified row.

In result I have:

```
gridOptions = {
  getRowNodeId: row => {
    return `${row.level0}${row.lastLevel}`;
  },
  ...
  columnTypes: {
    ...
    janType: {
      enableValue: true,
      aggFunc: 'sum',
      valueGetter: ({ data, getValue, api }) => {
        if (data.lastLevel === 'Net Income') {
          const in1Row = api.getRowNode('IncomeIn 1');
          const in2Row = api.getRowNode('IncomeIn 2');
 
          // Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
          return getValue("Jan", in1Row) + getValue("Jan", in2Row);
        }
        ...
        return data.Jan;
      }
    },
    ...
  },
};
```

This doesn't work and `getValue("Jan", in1Row) + getValue("Jan", in2Row)` causes `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

*Thanks for any ideas/examples in solving this case!*

Comment: I added a reference to the DEMO playground, https://plnkr.co/plunk/KQdZDjHKI0tUvT62. Hope that someone has ideas about this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it seems that the only possible way and place to implement this is to use the `onGridReady` event, and there it is possible to set values for calculated rows (via `rowNode.setDataValue()`). The grid has all data (+ aggregated data) at this stage. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69165943/9351185) is useful to understand how to collect all data.

The better way is to define `getRowNodeId` callback

```
getRowNodeId: row => {
   // custom rowNodeId resolver
},
```

and get values by data column and rowId (Jan, Feb, etc.).

Here is a simple implementation:

```
  onGridReady: ({ api }) => {
    const income = api.getRowNode('row-group-0');
    const in1Row = api.getRowNode('IncomeIn 1');
    const in2Row = api.getRowNode('IncomeIn 2');
    const liabilities = api.getRowNode('Liabilities');
    
    api.forEachNode(rowNode => console.log(rowNode.id));

    for (const col of ["Jan", "Feb"]) {
      const netIncome = api.getValue(col, in1Row) + api.getValue(col, in2Row) - api.getValue(col, liabilities);
      const netIncomeTotal = api.getValue(col, income) - api.getValue(col, liabilities);

      const netIncomeRow = api.getRowNode('Net Income');
      netIncomeRow.setDataValue(col, netIncome);

      const netIncomeTotalRow = api.getRowNode('Net Income Total');
      netIncomeTotalRow.setDataValue(col, netIncomeTotal);
    }
  }
```

***Reference to plunker [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/KQdZDjHKI0tUvT62).***

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Calculated Columns in AdapTable which we use in conjunction with AG Grid.

It gives you exactly what you want:  https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/handbook-calculated-column

Comment: Thank you for this reference, this library seems fine to cover the task!