# How to show total in ag-grid header

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How can I show total in header?

For example, I want to show sum of age as **Age(x)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ag-grid add `onRowDataChanged` event and create function.

```
<AgGridReact onRowDataChanged={onRowDataChanged}></AgGridReact>
```

Using ag-grid [column api](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-api/) to get column object and change its header name. After that, [refresh](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/#refreshing-headers) the header  component

```
const onRowDataChanged = (params) => {       
     var ageColumn = gridRef.current.columnApi.getColumn("age")
     var rowCount = gridRef.current.api.getDisplayedRowCount()
     ageColumn.colDef.headerName = `Age ${rowCount}`;
     gridRef.current.api.refreshHeader();
}
```

Comment: This worked for row count but as I was mentioning in the problem statement, I need to show sum of cells in a column as well. Is that achievable?

Comment: There must be a way to show total sum as well, I will look and post in answer. But as you mentioned in question you wanted to show total count not sum. Can you edit the question? **EDIT** Can I know by sum of cells you mean adding all the age values?

Comment: Sure, I will edit it Usama! Yeah, adding cells in that column

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399639/calculated-row-how-to-calculate-cell-value-of-the-particular-column-based-on-th) and [this](http://54.222.217.254/javascript-grid-accessing-data/#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20get,should%20always%20be%20strings%20gridOptions.) results. You need to get cell values and loop through them to sum the data. Currently, I dont have access to my system else I would have tried

Comment: Yep, tried and it worked Usama, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AdapTable with AG grid then you dont need any code.

Just set `showGroupingTotalsAsHeader` to true in General Options and AdapTable will do it for you:

https://docs.adaptabletools.com/guide/reference-options-general#showgroupingtotalsasheader

Comment: At no point did the OP say he was using AdapTable